# The way of mentioning an e-mail in a conversation

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Imagine a situation that you sent an e-mail to your friend but he did not reply for a week and you see him in a place. Do the following options suit in order to mention the e-mail in a conversation?

> Hey, how is it going? ~ Ah, I sent you an e-mail. Did you check it? Because, [.........]
>
> > I do not have your reply yet.
> >
> > You did not get back to me.
> >
> > You did not respond my e-mail.
> >
> > You did not sent back any feedback.

Which one is also a quick way to say it? ***or*** are there any other options?

Comment: all are okay except the last one! what's the problem?

Comment: *I sent you an email but there's no reply.* - shall convince everything - your sending, his receiving, his ignorance or the reason of not responding!

Comment: the problem is I just wanted to know the quicker way of saying it that's why I posted 4 different options that one of them can be simple and quicker to convey the subject.

Comment: You want shorter than this? *I sent you an email but there's no reply*

Comment: Thanks @MaulikV I think this would be the answer!. BTW why is the last one wrong, because of construction?

Comment: Yup! *feedback* seems that you have asked something for assessment, suggestion, improvement etc. Since I don't know the subject of your email, to be on the safe side, I said that ;)

Comment: "Why haven't you answered it?", is the fastest that I can think of.Only your second sentence is correct, in my opinion. The third should be like this: You did not respond to it. The fourth isn't appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All are okay (except the last one which means in the mail, you have asked for some suggestion, correction, improvement or opinion etc and a little *to* needed after respond in third option). **And,** there are many ways to ask that.

I'll write here what I'd prefer.

> I sent you an email but there's no reply.

This is one of the ways to convince everything what you want viz., You mailed, he received it, **and** somehow, there's no response. He might have missed it, didn't have time or might have considered not to reply or whatever the reason. If you stop after that sentence, anyone opposite to you is likely to clarify the matter. I think this is what you want ;)

*Why haven't you answered it* as stated in a comment is also correct but to me it seems a bit straightforward and somewhat ordering an answer ;) Anyway, that's my opinion though.

The fourth one doesn't fit here. If you are expecting a feedback, you must have asked about his opinion, suggestion, advice or the like. As you haven't specified the subject/context of that mail, I may not comment on this.

Comment: I agree; I would avoid the using _you_ as the subject. "You did not answer" or "You did not get back to me" sound accusatory, whereas "I have not heard back from you" or "I never got a reply" sound more congenial, and less confrontational. There are _dozens_ of ways one could say this, but I'd opt for one that is less likely to be misconstrued as accusing the person of being irresponsible.

Answer (score 0):

## Hey, I sent you an email last week, did you see it?

The four examples in the OP suggest various levels of confrontation.  It sounds a bit petty to beg for a reply.

If the content of the email required a response you could follow-up with something that describes the contents and what you wanted them to do with it.  Something like:

> ...it had some links to some cheese straighteners on Amazon.  I was hoping to get your opinion on which would be best one for my kitchen.

This way accomplishes the expression of your desires/expectations, while not *demanding* a response.  If they choose to, they will find it and reply.  If not, they aren't interested enough to help.  Either way, you aren't telling them what to do.

If the email didn't require a response, your friend could just tell you verbally that they received/read it:

> Yeah, cute kitten video!  I made it my screen-saver.